# Reading specific datafield out of database in Java

Tags: java, database, resultset

Some context first:

Part 1: I get all the values from column `VOTES` in a the table `SURVEYRESULTS`

Part 2: Every time I vote for a specific animal, `addVote()` will trigger with its specific parameter I know what animal needs an extra vote. So what I do next is add 1 vote to that animal.

For some reason the next thing happens:

Let's say all animals have 0 votes in my database. I then vote for "Dog". "Dog" then has 1 vote. I then vote again for "Dog", "Dog" won't have 2 votes, but still 1 vote instead.

So it seems that the code is working, but that `int voteDataDog` stays on value 0. I don't see why that would be though.

**Here is my code**:

```
int voteDataDog;
int voteDataCat;
int voteDataBird;
int voteDataSnake;
int voteDataNone;

// Part 1
public void getVoteData() throws SQLException{
    s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT VOTES FROM SURVEYRESULTS");
    while(rs.next()){
        voteDataDog = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataCat = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataBird = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataSnake = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataNone = rs.getInt("VOTES");
    }
}

//Part 2
public void addVote(String parameter) throws SQLException {

    this.getVoteData();

    if(parameter.equals("1")){
        voteDataDog ++;
        s.execute("UPDATE SURVEYRESULTS SET VOTES= " + this.voteDataDog + " WHERE ID=1");
    }

    if(parameter.equals("2")){
        voteDataCat ++;
        s.execute("UPDATE SURVEYRESULTS SET VOTES= " + voteDataCat + " WHERE ID=2");
    }

    if(parameter.equals("3")){
        voteDataBird ++;
        s.execute("UPDATE SURVEYRESULTS SET VOTES= " + voteDataBird + " WHERE ID=3");
    }

    if(parameter.equals("4")){
        voteDataSnake ++;
        s.execute("UPDATE SURVEYRESULTS SET VOTES= " + voteDataSnake + " WHERE ID=4");
    }

    if(parameter.equals("5")){
        voteDataNone ++;
        s.execute("UPDATE SURVEYRESULTS SET VOTES= " + voteDataNone + " WHERE ID=5");
    }

    rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyresults ORDER BY id");
    rmd = rs.getMetaData();
}
```

**Output example**:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID          SURVEYOPTION         VOTES       
1           Dog                  0           
2           Cat                  1           
3           Bird                 0           
4           Snake                0           
5           None                 0           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In fact I need the vote values for every animal.

```
int voteDataDog;
int voteDataCat; --> needs to become value '1' after Part 1
int voteDataBird;
int voteDataSnake;
int voteDataNone;
```

Comment: In the first part, you're initializing 5 different variables with the exact same value. That doesn't make much sense. And you're never reading the value of the variables anywhere,so it's unclear how you depermine that voteDataDog stays at 0. Post a complete minimal program, tell us what you expecte it to do precisely (i.e. post the expected output), and tell us what it does instead precisely (i.e. post its actual output).

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thanks already.
I've added an output example. In fact I need to read every seperate value from votes and define these values to my list of integers.
How should I do it in Part 1 instead?

Comment: Well with the comment of RDKaizhar I've got my answer already.
Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT VOTES FROM SURVEYRESULTS");
while(rs.next()){
        voteDataDog = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataCat = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataBird = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataSnake = rs.getInt("VOTES");
        voteDataNone = rs.getInt("VOTES");
    }
```

In here you are assigning the same value to every variable.

You execute the query "Select votes...". Lets say the first row returns 3.
Now the result set will assign 3 to voteDataDog, Cat, etc.
Now the result set goes to the next row that has a value of 0, now it assigns 0 to every animal.

Make a different query for each animal. Something like
"select votes from surveyresults where id = 1" for dogs and so on for every animal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT VOTES FROM SURVEYRESULTS");

    while(rs.next()){

        int currentId = rs.getInt("ID")

        //Shows the current id 
        System.out.printLn("Current ID = "+currentId);


        if(currentId == 1 ){

        voteDataDog = rs.getInt("VOTES");

        }else if(currentId == 2 ){

            voteDataCat = rs.getInt("VOTES");

        }else if(currentId == 3){

             voteDataBird = rs.getInt("VOTES");

        }else if(currentId == 4 ){

            voteDataSnake = rs.getInt("VOTES");

        }else if(currentId == 5){

            voteDataNone = rs.getInt("VOTES");

        }
    }
```